# Is there a way to make repeatedly forever apache beam trigger to only execute after the previous execution is completed?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using global window with repeated forever after processing time trigger to process streaming data from pub-sub as below :

```
PCollection<KV<String,SMMessage>> perMSISDNLatestEvents = messages
        .apply("Apply global window",Window.<SMMessage>into(new GlobalWindows())
                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
                .discardingFiredPanes())
        .apply("Convert into kv of msisdn and SM message", ParDo.of(new SmartcareMessagetoKVFn()))
        .apply("Get per MSISDN latest event",Latest.perKey()).apply("Write into Redis", ParDo.of(new WriteRedisFn()));
```

Is there a way to make repeatedly forever apache beam trigger to only execute after the previous execution is completed ? The reason for my question is because the next trigger processing will need to read data from redis, written by the previous trigger execution.

Thank You

Comment: It's a good practice here on Stack Overflow to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it was useful for you. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trigger here would fire at the interval you provided. The trigger is not aware of any downstream processing so it's unable to depend on such steps of your pipeline.

Instead of depending on the trigger for consistency here, you could add a barrier (a `DoFn`) that exists before the `Write` step and only gives up execution after you see the previous data in Redis.

Comment: what would be a barrier DoFn be like, Is it ok to provide example or pointer for this idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try and explicitly declare a global window trigger, as the example below:

```
Trigger subtrigger = AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane(); 
Trigger maintrigger = Repeatedly.forever(subtrigger);
```

I think that triggers would help you on your case, since it will allow you to create event times, which will run when you or your code trigger them, so you would only run repeatedly forever when a trigger finishes first.

I found [this documentation](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/triggers-apache-beam/read) which might guide you on the triggers you are trying to create.